# Pandas - Manipulating strings and filling columns based on character sequences in strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of protein sequences (strings) like the following:

| Sequence |
| --- |
| `PANTHER:PTN000391532|MGI:MGI:1933972|MGI:MGI:106016|UniProtKB:P62995|RGD:1306751` |
| `PANTHER:PTN002926186|UniProtKB:Q9NQ88` |
| `PANTHER:PTN000670347|UniProtKB:P10632|UniProtKB:P11509|UniProtKB:P33261|UniProtKB:P20813` |
|  |

This is the output (pandas dataframe) that I'm trying to achieve:

| PANTHER | MGI | UniProtKB | RGD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `PTN000391532` | `[1933972, 106016]` | `P62995` | `1306751` |
| `PTN002926186` |  | `Q9NQ88` |  |
| `PTN000670347` |  | `[P10632, P11509, P33261, P20813]` |  |
|  |  |  |  |

For each row in the original dataframe, I have separated the sequence at the pipe, but I'm not sure if this is a useful first step.
For the first row, I got `['PANTHER:PTN000391532', 'MGI:MGI:1933972', 'MGI:MGI:106016', 'UniProtKB:P62995', 'RGD:1306751']`.

For each of the separated values in each sequence, I want to create a new column for each unique prefix before the colon. So in the case of the first row, I would have 4 columns - `PANTHER`, `MGI`, `UniProtKB`, and `RGD`.

Then, I want to take the values after the colons and put them into their corresponding column. For example, I want to take the values after "PANTHER:" and put them into the column `PANTHER`. For the values beginning with `MGI:MGI:`, I want to take the value after "MGI:MGI:" and put it into the column `MGI`. Since there are multiple values beginning with the same prefix in some rows (row 1 and row 3 in this case), I want to have a list of values when there are multiple values. So for the first row, the `MGI` column would have a list like `[1933972, 106016]`.

If a sequence is null (blank row), I want the output dataframe to also have blank entries.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = []
for i in df.Sequence.to_list():
    if i is np.NAN:
        result.append({'PANTHER':np.NAN})
    else:
        temp = defaultdict(list)
        for j in i.split('|'):
            k = j.rsplit(':',1)
            temp[k[0]].append(k[1])
        result.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Output:

| PANTHER | MGI:MGI | UniProtKB | RGD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ['PTN000391532'] | ['1933972', '106016'] | ['P62995'] | ['1306751'] |
| ['PTN002926186'] |  | ['Q9NQ88'] |  |
| ['PTN000670347'] |  | ['P10632', 'P11509', 'P33261', 'P20813'] |  |

Comment: How would you handle NA values? Like if one of the sequences were NA?

Comment: Can you add one example to your question? @nerdygril

Comment: Hi! I added an example. Basically, how would you handle a blank row? @Nk03

Comment: @nerdygril updated my answer. I assummed  by blank you mean the value is NAN. Please make the required changes